Regular Expression for string of alphanumeric codes (ICD-10) regardless of whether it has a period in the middle or not
I'm currently working on a script that creates an ICD-10 code block/range based on the given ICD-10 code. I've made some progress for those having four or more characters but if the given ICD-10 code is a 3-character code, my regex code doesn't work as it should. It seems like the problem lies with the period in between the alphanumeric codes. Here's my current code:
icd10 <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  check.names = FALSE,
  `icd10_codes` = c("A00-A09.9","A00.1","A01.2","A00-A09.9","A04.4",
                      "A00","A05","A00-A09.9","A03.2")) %>% 

  # Identify the ICD-10 Block Codes
  mutate(icdrange = case_when(
    grepl('^([a-zA-Z0-9]*-[a-zA-Z0-9]*)+$', icd10_codes) ~ icd10_codes,   # if ICD-10 code is already a block code, use it as the ICD-10 range
    grepl('^([aA][0][0-9][.]*[0-9][0-9]*)+$', icd10_codes) ~ "A00-A09.9",
    grepl('^([aA][1][5-9][.]*[0-9][0-9]*)+$', icd10_codes) ~ "A15.0-A19.9",
    grepl('^([aA][2][7][.]*[0-9][0-9]*)+$', icd10_codes) ~ "A27.0-A27.9",
    grepl('^([aA][3-4][0-9][.]*[0-9][0-9]*)+$', icd10_codes) ~ "A30-A49.9",
    grepl('^([aA][8][0-9][.]*[0-9][0-9]*)+$', icd10_codes) ~ "A80-A89"
  ))

A01.1 should be assigned to A00-A09.9 (this currently works)
A00 should be assigned to A00-A09.9 (not currently working)
I hope you could help. Thank you!

For the first case, you can use ^([a-zA-Z][0-9]{2}-[a-zA-Z][0-9]{2}).
For the others, you can use ^[aA][0][0-9]([.][0-9])?$
  # Identify the ICD-10 Block Codes
  df %>% mutate(icdrange = case_when(
    # if ICD-10 code is already a block code, use it as the ICD-10 range
    grepl('^([a-zA-Z][0-9]{2}-[a-zA-Z][0-9]{2})', icd10_codes) ~ icd10_codes,   
    
    grepl('^[aA][0][0-9]([.][0-9])?$', icd10_codes) ~ "A00-A09.9",
    grepl('^[aA][1][5-9]([.][0-9])?$', icd10_codes) ~ "A15.0-A19.9",
    grepl('^[aA][2][7]([.][0-9])?$', icd10_codes) ~ "A27.0-A27.9",
    grepl('^[aA][3-4][0-9]([.][0-9])?$', icd10_codes) ~ "A30-A49.9",
    grepl('^[aA][8][0-9]([.][0-9])?$', icd10_codes) ~ "A80-A89"
  ))


  icd10_codes  icdrange
1   A00-A09.9 A00-A09.9
2       A00.1 A00-A09.9
3       A01.2 A00-A09.9
4   A00-A09.9 A00-A09.9
5       A04.4 A00-A09.9
6         A00 A00-A09.9
7         A05 A00-A09.9
8   A00-A09.9 A00-A09.9
9       A03.2 A00-A09.9



A01.1 should be assigned to A00-A09.9 (this currently works) A00
should be assigned to A00-A09.9 (not currently working)

This statement would be fixed by the following regex. All though your business objective is not pretty clear so I have kept last + in this regex as you desired.
^([aA][0][0-9]([.][0-9])?[0-9]?)+$

Demo
Explanation:

([.][0-9])? ensures that when . exists it is followed by  1 digit.
The final ? ensures that .digit is optional.
[0-9]? - ensures that the final digit is also optional.
I have also replaced * into ? because it is not quite clear as in why you need zero or more when you only want to keep it optional.

